# Unzip file using SSZipArchive not extracting zip file

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, unzip, ssziparchive

I am downloading a zipped folder using AFNetworking library, file is downloading but when i am trying to Un zip that zip folder, it is not opening. On mac machine it is also not extracting on double click and by Archive Utility.

```
NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask = [manager downloadTaskWithRequest:request progress:nil destination:^NSURL *(NSURL *targetPath, NSURLResponse *response) {
    NSURL *documentsDirectoryURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask appropriateForURL:nil create:NO error:nil];
    return [documentsDirectoryURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:[response suggestedFilename]];
} completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSURL *filePath, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"File downloaded to: %@", filePath);
    [SSZipArchive unzipFileAtPath:[filePath path] toDestination: [[filePath path] stringByDeletingLastPathComponent]];
}];
```

Comment: What kind of error throws in `SSZipArchive`?

Comment: Set attributes failed for directory: 2017-09-07 10_06_53.zip/.storage.

Comment: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "The file “.storage” doesn’t exist." UserInfo={NSFilePath=2017-09-07 10_06_53.zip/.storage, NSUnderlyingError=0x600000053ce0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}

Comment: what is ur destination path ? I think problem is there at destination path may be wrong.

Comment: My source and destination path same, document directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
   NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
   NSString *path = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"vikas.sqlite"];
   NSString *outputPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
   [SSZipArchive unzipFileAtPath:path toDestination:outputPath delegate:self];
```

Unzip file will be on Output Path.

Answer (score 1):

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *basePath = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;

```
NSString *destinationPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/filepath",basepath]];
[SSZipArchive basePath toDestination:destinationPath overwrite:NO password:nil error:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
[SSZipArchive unzipFileAtPath:[filePath path] toDestination: [[filePath path] stringByDeletingLastPathComponent]];
```

use:

```
[SSZipArchive unzipFileAtPath:zipPath toDestination:destinationPath overwrite:NO password:nil error:nil]
```

to unzip the file

Comment: [Please format your code properlly](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: Not working with this code also, same error appearing.